# Can I install Ubuntu from a external hard drive?

Tags: installation, usb, usb-drive

I have a very simple question... Is it possible to install Ubuntu from a external harddrive? If it is where can I get information on to do it?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be possible using [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/).

There is also [this](http://agnipulse.com/2011/08/install-ubuntu-hard-disk/) tutorial

Answer (score 2):

Unetbootin will create a startup disk on an external drive but I prefer using **usb-creator.exe** for Windows.

It is made specificaly for installing Ubuntu to USB drives.

It can be extracted from the Ubuntu iso file using 7zip.

Alternatly, the Linux version, **Startup Disk Creator**, can be run from the Live CD or an existing Ubuntu install.

Don't forget to set your BIOS to boot this drive first.

Answer (score 1):

Just treat Your HD like an ordinary USB drive. You have a tutorial how to set up a bootable USB version on Ubuntu download website.
The important thing then is to allow in BIOS to use Your HD as a booting device